# embed google qrcode in email

Tags: asp-classic, qr-code

I have a code that sends an email with embeded images using aspemail.

within the code i get a regular image by the `<img> tag` from google - so i get the qrcode

in the email, if the client does not download images automaticaly, he won't see the image

the embed of aspemail can't embed image/file that is not local

is there a way to save locally an image from a giving url?

if i get image from google: `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://www.sitedomain.com&choe=UTF-8`

and have it saved as a unique name under specific folder

Comment: i have found the solution with xmlhttp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function SaveBinaryData(FileName, ByteArray)
  Const adTypeBinary = 1
  Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

  Dim BinaryStream
  Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary

  BinaryStream.Open
  BinaryStream.Write ByteArray

  BinaryStream.SaveToFile FileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
End Function

Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
' Point to an image file with adequate access permissions granted
objHTTP.open "GET", "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://www.domian.com&choe=UTF-8",false
objHTTP.send
'Response.BinaryWrite objHTTP.ResponseBody
call SaveBinaryData(Server.MapPath(".") & "\test.png", objHTTP.ResponseBody)
Set objHTTP = Nothing
```

Comment: If your ASPEmail component edition supports [AddEmbeddedImageMem](http://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html#AddEmbeddedImageMem) method, you can use it as `your_mail_object.AddEmbeddedImageMem "name","content_id", objHTTP.ResponseBody`. That eliminates need to Stream object.

Comment: just finished try this... had the objhttp returned from function so i put it into adbodb.stream but the when i have used the cid:qrcode i get a gray square in the email

Comment: can any one tell me if it is not working anymore because of google?