# Persits.MailSender.4 error '800a0007' upon calling objMail.AddEmbeddedImage

Tags: asp-classic

I'm using **Persits AspEmail** for sending emails in a Classic ASP application. I've used it many times before but I had never come across the following issue:

I need to embed an image into the body of an email, but this image is actually virtual (I'm using IIS Rewrite to handle all URL rewrites, so when an image is requested from a specific directory, IIS Rewrite calls an .asp page that displays the image using the Persits AspJpeg component), but when I try to do it, AspEmail returns this error:

```
Persits.MailSender.4 error '800a0007'
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Any other image that is not virtual will get embedded.

The code is simple:

```
Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
...
objMail.AddEmbeddedImage virtualImageUrl, virtualImageCid
...
objMail.Send
```

Am I doing something wrong here? If AspEmail can't handle virtual files, is there a way around this? Please, other than using FSO to temporarily copy the file to a directory in order to embed it, or leaving the image on the server -- I really need it to be embedded.

Thank you (a lot!) in advance,

Cheers,

Mark

P.S.: My server is running IIS 7.5 / IIS Rewrite Module 2 / AspEmail v5.1.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

**AddEmbeddedImage** property needs a physical path. And it doesn't make an http request (to getting dynamic script response).

> **4.2 The AddEmbeddedImage Method** (http://www.aspemail.com/manual_04.html#4_2)
> AspEmail offers support for embedded images via the method AddEmbeddedImage which takes two arguments:
>   ***`the physical path to an image file`***, and its Content ID, which is simply an
>   arbitrary string without spaces.
> If your message contains multiple
>   embedded images, each must be assigned a unique Content ID.

But there is another property more appropriate than AddEmbeddedImage to using dynamic images.
You need make an http request and pass the response to your AspEmail instance using **[AddEmbeddedImageMem](http://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html#AddEmbeddedImageMem)** property.

Similar solution: [embed google qrcode in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280817/embed-google-qrcode-in-email/7281018#comment8767793_7281018)

Comment: Kul-Tigin, thanks a lot, you got that right, I was trying to do something that the `AddEmbeddedImage` method is not meant for. I finally got it to work with `AddEmbeddedImageMem`, as you suggested. I'm posting the relevant code for others who might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

Since I'm also using **Persits AspJpeg** to generate the virtual image, I used the `objAspJpeg.Binary` property to save the image temporarily to a variable, and then passed this variable to `objMail.AddEmbeddedImageMem` method, and voilà.

```
'First: AspJpeg to process and generate the virtual binary image.'

Set objAspJpeg = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Jpeg")
objAspJpeg.Open(Server.MapPath(physicalImgUrl))   'Actual, physical image.'

'...some image processing: resizing, etc...'

processedVirtualImg = objAspJpeg.Binary   'Generated virtual image.'
Set objAspJpeg      = Nothing

'Second: AspEmail to embed the virtual image and send the email.'

Set objMail    = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
objMail.Host   = "www.example.com"
'< the rest of the config parameters here >'

objMail.Body   = "<img src=""cid:virtualImgId"" />"
objMail.IsHTML = True

objMail.AddEmbeddedImageMem "image.jpg", "virtualImgId", processedVirtualImg

objMail.Queue  = True
objMail.Send

Set objMail    = Nothing
```